# how to import chrome bookmark from windows into ubuntu browser(mozila)

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, bookmarks, ubuntu-12.04

I was a windows user for last 5 years but wanted to switch into Ubuntu World. I saved too many (around 100) bookmarks into chrome while using Windows. Now I want to import those bookmarks into Ubuntu browser (Firefox). Can you please help me to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are [supposed to be related to programming](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). Your question is off-topic here, it might be better off on http://superuser.com.

Comment: K....i m posting this question to superuser.com. Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got a gmail account?  If you have one, you could login in the preference of chrome in both systems.  Then the bookmarks would be automatically synchronized.